# nginx poodle fix configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a dedicated CentOS web server (with Plesk 12) and I am trying to disable SSL 3.
I have been everywhere trying to disable SSL 3 and tried to apply the fix as detailed within other posts, but when I retest (using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d) the server it still shows that SSL 3 is available.
I have been to my server supplier and they have not been very helpful at all.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file looks like

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include   mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain image/svg+xml text/css application/json application/x$
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    server_tokens off;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


 server {

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 }

}
```

After I apply the above I have restarted the service with  `sudo service nginx restart`

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: have you modified /etc/nginx/sites-available/default this file ? If not then make the changes in this file as well. Do grep -R "SSL" /etc/nginx/sites-* then make the changes in every output file .

Comment: @P4cK3tHuNt3R thank you for replying. When i open these files they are completly blank do i just add 
http { server {

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 }

} to them?

Comment: have you grepped using the above command grep -R "ssl_protocols" /etc/nginx/sites-*.

Comment: If still it is blank then you have to google for sample of these files after that make the changes.

Comment: maybe related: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254016

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that you use the Mozilla SSL configuration tool found [here](http://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/).

They keep it up-to-date, it covers Apache and Nginx and it shows you all of the parameters.

Here is an extract from my own default site configuration:

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

server_name ubuntu;

# ---- SSL Configuration - Use http://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ to update ---- #
# Includes PFS, Cert Pinning, SPDY

# certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

# Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
# Generate with: cd /etc/ssl/certs && sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

# modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# HSTS
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

# OCSP Stapling ---
# fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
#ssl_stapling on;
#ssl_stapling_verify on;

## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
#For StartSSL goto ‘Toolbox’ and ‘StartCom CA Certificates’ and is called ‘Server Certificate Bundle with CRLs’.
#ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;
#resolver 8.8.8.8;
# ---- End of SSL Config ---- #
```

Note that I've not enabled OCSP stapling because this is taken from a local development server running on a VirtualBox guest so it only has a self-signed certificate.

Comment: You are missing `TLSv1` and will lose a lot of somewhat older browsers (mobile phones, IE, Safari...)

Comment: Not missing :) That was deliberate. I guess I should add an annotation to that effect. TLS v1 also has vulnerabilities. But thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for commenting. I finally managed to find a solution

http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/ssl-poodle-sslv3-bug.323338/

First I would like to thank UFHH01 for the solution provided, our exposure is resolved for now! Hope you don't mind, I have compiled all steps below:

Updated: Be sure you are using the correct directory for the templates.
"/opt/psa/admin/conf/templates/default" is not the same as "/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/" this might be distro specific or a typo on one or ther other...for me I used /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/

Ensure you first run the commands:

cd /etc/nginx/
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096

Grab a cup of coffee, this will be a while....[elevator music] When it completes you should be back to the shell prompt.

Updated:Make the directory /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/ if it does not already exist. When copying files to custom templates, ensure you are using the same directory structure and only copy over files you will be editing.

Commands:

mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom
cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/nginxWebmailPartial.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/
cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/server/nginxVhosts.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/server/
cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
cd /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/

Make the following code changes to the files below now located in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/

"nginxWebmailPartial.php" "server/nginxVhosts.php" "domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php"

Code:

ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

After changes have been made be sure to:

/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
service httpd restart
service nginx restart

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by making this your default:

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-SSLv3:-EXP:!kEDH;

Inorder to disable support for SSLv3 (poodle vunerablity) you have to add -SSLv3 to your ciphers as well as use TLS options only in your protocols like I mentioned in the exact example I gave you above to use in your server blocks.

When you do this, you can check to see if it worked by visiting: https://www.poodlescan.com/

Hope that helps